# Render different HTML content based on object property in Angular?

Tags: angular, angularjs

I am looping through data in my TS Component and want to render different data than the object property itself.

For example right now              `<strong>{{ item.status }}</strong>`

It is rendering success because it is the value of the property object.
But I want it to render a different text content value if its success and so on.

Is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: Sure. You can do things like {{ item.status === ‘success’ ? ‘Whoho!’ : ‘I failed you’ }}

Answer (score 0):

You just need a ngIf, for example:

```
<strong *ngIf="item.status === 'success'">Whatever you want to display when the status is success</strong>
<strong *ngIf="item.status === 'fail'">Whatever you want to display when the status is fail</strong>
```

You could also use `ngSwitch` but depending on what you are trying to do, `ngIf` might easier to follow